# IguanaTex with Powerpoint, I'm not able to reference the equations

Tags: powerpoint, iguanatex

I'm using IguanaTex with Powerpoint to make the presentation of my Thesis, but I'm not able to reference the equations.
Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq,amsmath}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\color{yellow}
\begin{equation} \label{T1}
l = \log \int f_{\bm{Y}|\textbf{b}}(\bm{y}|\textbf{b})f_U({b})db = \log f_{\bm{Y}}(\bm{y}).
\end{equation}
Desta forma,
\begin{eqnarray} \label{EqVero}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta} &=\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \int f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}) f_{U}(\mathbf{b}) d_\mathbf{b} / f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) \\
&=\int\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} f_{Y \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})\right] f_{\mathbf{U}}(\mathbf{b}) d_\mathbf{b} / f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}),
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

porque $f_U(\bm{b})$ não envolve $\bm{\beta}$. Porém,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}) &=\left(\frac{1}{f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})} \frac{\partial f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}\left(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}\right)}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})  
\vspace{17cm}\\
&=\frac{\partial \log f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\noindent então, podemos reescrever \eqref{EqVero} e \eqref{T1}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta} &=\int \frac{\partial \log f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}) f_{\mathbf{U}}(\mathbf{b}) d_\mathbf{b} / f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) \\
&=\int \frac{\partial \log f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{U} \mid \mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{b} \mid \mathbf{y}) d_\mathbf{b}.
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but why don't you use `beamer` instead?

Comment: @BlackBird Thanks for the sugestion. I already have some powerpoint slides. I will include some slides with mathematical formulas. So, I think IguanaTex is easier.

Comment: Good luck with "easier", hope it works.

Comment: @BlackBird Thanks. It is not just easier. As I mentioned, I have several slides ready in powerpoint. In addition, there are 3 slides that I want to include with mathematical formulas. I just have to solve this problem. Thanks again for the suggestion, I will certainly try to learn more Beamer.

Comment: What is the status of this answer? I am currently not able to get \ref or \eqref to work with iguanatex. Do you have a more up to date version? A google ground from the author of the software and a posted solution to this is located here:
[Google Group Link](https://groups.google.com/g/iguanatex/c/ZPqszb0tpQo/m/nOE60DnYAAAJ)

Answer (score 4):

I just tried your code and it work perfectly fine. To see the result clearly, I commented off the line that colors the page yellow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq,amsmath}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%\color{yellow}
\begin{equation} \label{T1}
l = \log \int f_{\bm{Y}|\textbf{b}}(\bm{y}|\textbf{b})f_U({b})db = \log f_{\bm{Y}}(\bm{y}).
\end{equation}
Desta forma,
\begin{eqnarray} \label{EqVero}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta} &=\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \int f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}) f_{U}(\mathbf{b}) d_\mathbf{b} / f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) \\
&=\int\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} f_{Y \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})\right] f_{\mathbf{U}}(\mathbf{b}) d_\mathbf{b} / f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}),
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

porque $f_U(\bm{b})$ não envolve $\bm{\beta}$. Porém,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}) &=\left(\frac{1}{f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})} \frac{\partial f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}\left(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}\right)}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})  
\vspace{17cm}\\
&=\frac{\partial \log f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\noindent então, podemos reescrever \eqref{EqVero} e \eqref{T1}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta} &=\int \frac{\partial \log f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b}) f_{\mathbf{U}}(\mathbf{b}) d_\mathbf{b} / f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) \\
&=\int \frac{\partial \log f_{\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{b}}(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{b})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} f_{\mathbf{U} \mid \mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{b} \mid \mathbf{y}) d_\mathbf{b}.
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I guess you just have to update your IguanaTex to the latest version to get everything right.

Comment: I appreciate your attention, but this question was asked 7 months ago. The Author of the software talked to me by email and updated it, removing this problem.